# how to implement protocol as I did in android

Tags: java, android, ios, swift3, protocols

```
DialogManager.showDialog(this, message, new OnTwoButtonClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onButtonClick1() {}                                        

               @Override
               public void onButtonClick2() {}                       
           });
```

How could I create same functionality in swift 3.

As far as I know I can't create new instance from protocol.

I know about delegation and I know I can do that way but I am looking for another solution.

I want my dialog usage will be as mentioned above.

Could anyone suggest me best solution?

Comment: Are you trying to create a dialog yourself, instead of using `AlertDialog` in Android or `UIAlertController` in iOS?

Comment: I am creating dialog myself I didn't use any native controls

Comment: @Sweeper the main idea how to use protocols in swift not about how to create alertdialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *closures*.

`showDialog` would be defined like this:

```
func showDialog(message: String, 
    button1Click: @escaping () -> Void, 
    button2Click: @escaping () -> Void)
```

To trigger the closures, do:

```
button1Click()
button2Click()
```

To call `showDialog`, do:

```
showDialog(message: "Hello", 
           button1Click: { // code },
           button2Click: { // code })
```